# How to create logout function in Ionic 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, logout

I would like to create a logout button in my Ionic 2+ application.

My problem is this:

When I click on the logout button on ProfilePage, I get a redirect to WelcomePage and then there is a second redirect back to ProfilePage (which is the page where the logout button is located).

How can I block this second redirect?

Here is my html code :

```html
        </p>
        <a href="#" (click)="logout()" button ion-button block color="danger" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='log-out'></ion-icon>
            Se déconnecter
        </a>
```

And my JS function:

```js
    logout(){
      this.navCtrl.push('WelcomePage');
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are saying that once you click the logout button it's redirect you to the welcome page and after clicking the back button it redirect you to the profile page or it auto redirect to the profile page?

Comment: No when I click on the button, I am redirected to the WelcomePage then about 1 second later, I am automatically redirected to my previous page

Comment: Maybe you should share more your code to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: You can see more code below

Answer (score 1):

So Ionic is using so called "nav stack", where there is (should be) a root page and then other pages might either:

- replace rootPage or
- be pushed on top (= stacked on top)

Think of Ionic Nav Stack as this coin analogy:

[image]

So you can replace initial coin (your rootPage is such a coin) and you can push in more coins (pages) or pop them (remove Pages) from the stack.

Now for your question - in your case seems like you don't perform pop on other pages / nor you replace rootPage, or in other way manage the stack properly.
Depending on your user experience you probably want to return a user to the state of the app that occurs on their login.

Normally if your original (rootPage) is Welcome Page, what you want to do is to get back to that page (rootPage) using

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot

So depending on what your root page is (you don't provide code that has that context unfortunately) you could:

```
logout(){
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
}
```

I would suggest you to think of your nav stack strategy annd decide when to assign new rootPage and when to push/pop.

In my experience I normally always replace rootPage when it is a whole new page / topic / theme I am navigating user to, and I am using push only if its another page/modal that is relevant to the rootPage.

Another way of looking into this: you don't want your stack to be huge (constantly pushing in new pages) and you don't want user to travel "back" (pop) for more than 2-3 layers.

Comment: You can see my app.component.ts code in my Edit above

I tried to use this.navCtrl.popToRoot(); but now when I click on the logout button, I am redirected directly to my profile page (without going through the WelcomePage)

Comment: so can you describe what is your strategy around the stack? your code states that your rootPage is either DevPage Or WelcomePage? You need to define what is the desired stack first (like rootPage is always WelcomePage, then on successful login you set rootPage to ProfilePage etc etc). Share that strategy then it will be easy to help you achieve what you need (redirect user to initial page)

Answer (score 0):

For more details of my code:

Profile.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from './../../models/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WelcomePage } from '../pages';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {
    
    user = {} as User;
    
    pageTitle = "Profile";
    disableForm: Boolean = true;
    email: string;
    idUser: string = '';
    
    /**
    * @text to integrate with back API and database
    * NOT FINISHED
    */
    profile = {
        coverImage: 'assets/img/splashbg.png',
        contact: 'Pour exercer les droits utilisateurs, contacter nous via ce formulaire.',
        mentions: 'Lisez les mentions légales en cliquant ici:',
        password: 'Pour modifier votre mot de passe cliquez ci-dessous:',
        logout: 'Se déconnecter, bouton juste en dessous.',
        delete: 'Supprimer définitivement mon compte.'
    };
    
    /**
    * @data userTest to implements with the API
    * NOT FINISHED
    */
    userTest = {
        username: 'romain',
        profileImage: 'assets/img/romain.jpg',
        country: 'France',
        city: 'Paris',
        description: '',
        languages: ['Français', 'Anglais'],
    };
    
    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        private aFAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController
    ) {  
        this.aFAuth.authState.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.idUser = data.uid;
                this.email = data.email;
            }
        )
    }
    
    ionViewWillLoad() {
        console.log('profile page loaded');
    } 
    
    
    ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.idUser = this.aFAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Edit user information (Firebase and Database)
    * NOT FINISHED
    * @method edit
    */
    edit(user){
        this.disableForm = !this.disableForm;
        console.log(user);
        // check if entries are empty
        // update entries in firebase 
        // update entries in database
    };
    
    /**
    * Edit password with Firebase API
    * 
    * @method editPassword
    * return nothing but the user get's an email
    */
    editPassword(){
        if(this.email == null) {
            const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Email vide!',
                subTitle: 'Contacter le support.',
                buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
        } else {
            this.aFAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);
            const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Email envoyé!',
                subTitle: 'Un email vous a été envoyé. Veuillez y suivre les instructions.',
                buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
        }
    };
    
    /**
    * Delete an user from profile page with Firebase.
    * NOT FINISHED still an console error but the user is deleted
    * @method deleteUser
    */
    deleteUser(){

        var userDelete = this.aFAuth.auth.currentUser;
        
        const deleteConfirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Suppression de compte ?',
            message: 'Cette action va supprimer votre compte ainsi que toutes les données qui y sont relié. Cette action est irrévocable.',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Non',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Non');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Ok',               
                    handler: () => {
                        try {
                            userDelete.delete();
                            console.log('deleted');
                            this.navCtrl.push('WelcomePage');
                        } catch(e){
                            this.navCtrl.push('WelcomePage');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        deleteConfirm.present();
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Log out with Firebase Web API signOut method
    * NOT FINISHED error on uid
    * @method logOut
    */
    logout(){
        try {
            this.navCtrl.push('WelcomePage');
            console.log('User logged out 1');
        } catch {
            this.navCtrl.push('WelcomePage');
            console.log('User logged out 2');
        }

        console.log('User logged out 3');
    }
}
```

Profile.html

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Profil</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content parallax-header no-bounce class="bg-modal">
    <div class="header-image">
        <button ion-button (click)="edit(user)" color="secondary" item-end medium>
            <ion-icon name='create'></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content" text-wrap text-center>
        <div class="circular"></div>
        <h2>{{userTest.username}}</h2>
        <p class="profile-description">{{userTest.description}}</p>
        <ion-list no-lines>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="mail" color="primary" item-start></ion-icon>
                <ion-input placeholder="Email" type="email" class="profile-text" id="profile-input" [(ngModel)]="email" [readonly]="disableForm"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="home" color="primary" item-start></ion-icon>
                <ion-input placeholder="City" type="text" class="profile-text" id="profile-input" [(ngModel)]="userTest.city" [readonly]="disableForm"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="home" color="primary" item-start></ion-icon>
                <ion-input placeholder="Country" type="text" class="profile-text" id="profile-input" [(ngModel)]="userTest.country" [readonly]="disableForm"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="chatbubbles" color="primary" item-start></ion-icon>
                <ion-input placeholder="Langues" type="text" class="profile-text" id="profile-input" [(ngModel)]="userTest.languages" [readonly]="disableForm"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <hr><hr>
        <p class="profile-text">
            {{profile.password}}
        </p>
        <a href="#" (click)="editPassword(user)" button ion-button block color="primary" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='finger-print'></ion-icon>
            Mot de passe
        </a>
        <p class="profile-text">
            {{profile.contact}}
        </p>
        <a href="#" button ion-button block color="secondary" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='contact'></ion-icon>
            Formulaire de contact
        </a>
        <p class="profile-text">
            {{profile.mentions}}    
        </p>
        <a href="#" button ion-button block color="secondary" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='copy'></ion-icon>
            Lire les mentions légales
        </a>

        <br>
        <hr>
        <p class="profile-text">
            {{profile.logout}}
        </p>
        <a href="#" (click)="logout()" button ion-button block color="danger" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='log-out'></ion-icon>
            Se déconnecter
        </a>
        
        <br>
        <hr>
        <p class="profile-text">
            {{profile.delete}}
        </p>
        <a href="#" (click)="deleteUser()" button ion-button block color="danger" icon-start>
            <ion-icon name='trash'></ion-icon>
            Supprimer mon compte
        </a>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Welcome.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * The Welcome Page is a splash page that quickly describes the app,
 * and then directs the user to create an account or log in.
 * If you'd like to immediately put the user onto a login/signup page,
 * we recommend not using the Welcome page.
*/
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-welcome',
  templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
})
export class WelcomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
  ) { }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(false);
  }

  login() {
    this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
  }

  register() {
    this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
// import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
// import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Config, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { WelcomePage, DevPage } from '../pages/pages';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = DevPage ? DevPage : WelcomePage;

    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  pages: any[] = [
    { title: 'Tutorial', component: 'TutorialPage' },
    { title: 'Welcome', component: 'WelcomePage' },
    { title: 'Tabs', component: 'TabsPage' },
    { title: 'Cards', component: 'CardsPage' },
    { title: 'Content', component: 'ContentPage' },
    { title: 'Login', component: 'LoginPage' },
    { title: 'Master Detail', component: 'ListMasterPage' },
    { title: 'Menu', component: 'MenuPage' },
    { title: 'Messages', component: 'MessagesPage' },
    { title: 'Search', component: 'SearchPage' },
    { title: 'Profile', component: 'ProfilePage' }
  ]

  constructor(
      private translate: TranslateService, 
      platform: Platform, 
      private config: Config, 
    //   private statusBar: StatusBar, 
    //   private splashScreen: SplashScreen
      ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('dev page : ', DevPage);
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    //   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    //   this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.initTranslate();
  }

    initTranslate() {
        // Set the default language for translation strings, and the current language.
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        const browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();

        if (browserLang) {
            if (browserLang === 'zh') {
                const browserCultureLang = this.translate.getBrowserCultureLang();

                if (browserCultureLang.match(/-CN|CHS|Hans/i)) {
                    this.translate.use('zh-cmn-Hans');
                } else if (browserCultureLang.match(/-TW|CHT|Hant/i)) {
                    this.translate.use('zh-cmn-Hant');
                }
            } else {
                this.translate.use(this.translate.getBrowserLang());
            }
        } else {
            this.translate.use('en'); // Set your language here
        }

        this.translate.get(['BACK_BUTTON_TEXT']).subscribe(values => {
            this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
        });
    }

    openPage(page) {
        // Reset the content nav to have just this page
        // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
        this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try..

```
logout(){
     //clear any storage and cached data
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
}
```